# AI returning to original position

Tags: unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

I want my enemy to move back to starting position. He follows me until I get out of his range and then he just stops.
Also i want my skeleton to stop for like 5 sec, and then go back to starting point, any ideas ? I never did anything involving time, exept stopping it.
Here is my script for enemy:

Also here is a screenshoot of inspector on the skeleton: [enemy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOd8k.jpg)
Here is my script for enemy:

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class chase : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    private Animator anim;
    public float LookRadius = 15f;
    public Transform enemyStartPos;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        this.enemyStartPos.position = this.transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (!PauseMenu.GameIsPaused)
        {
            if (Vector3.Distance(player.position, this.transform.position) < 15)
            {
                Vector3 direction = player.position - this.transform.position;
                direction.y = 0;
                this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(this.transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(direction), 0.1f);

                anim.SetBool("isIdle", false);
                if (direction.magnitude > 3)
                {
                    this.transform.Translate(0, 0, 0.05f);
                    anim.SetBool("isWalking", true);
                    anim.SetBool("isAttacking", false);
                }
                else
                {
                    anim.SetBool("isAttacking", true);
                    anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                if (Vector3.Distance(this.enemyStartPos.position, this.transform.position) >1)
                {
                    Vector3 direction = this.enemyStartPos.position - this.transform.position;
                    direction.y = 0;
                    this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(this.transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(direction), 0.1f);

                    anim.SetBool("isIdle", false);
                    if (direction.magnitude > 1)
                    {
                        this.transform.Translate(0, 0, 0.05f);
                        anim.SetBool("isWalking", true);
                        anim.SetBool("isAttacking", false);
                    }
                }
                else
                anim.SetBool("isIdle", true);
                anim.SetBool("isAttacking", false);
                anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, LookRadius);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you try to "code" this, think about it in terms of your program design.  You have designed and implemented behavior that says "if the bot's position is within X units of the player's position, turn the bot and move it toward the player."

What you describe wanting to do next can be thought of in the same way (which should lead to similar code).. "else, if the bot's position is NOT within X units of the player's position, turn the bot and move it toward [origin]."  Note, this means you need to define what [origin] is for the bot.  Point being, it makes no difference in the code whether you are moving toward a player or some arbitrary fixed point.  The code to move one transform toward another transform is the same.

For "wandering" it's essentially the same thought process:  If bot is within X units of [origin] and not following player, pick a random direction and move that way.  (better yet, pick a random direction and move that way for some amount of time so your bot doesn't just jitter around origin).

Comment: I get the idea, is it better to do with NavMesh or with code ? I know you can do some sort of waypoints in NavMesh, but for code, i have no idea how to get the starting position of the enemy. Maybe something like public Transform enemy; and do Vector3.Distance( this.transform.position, enemy.position )??

Comment: To get starting position of enemy, one approach would be to do something like these steps:
1.  Declare an attribute like "private Transform enemyStartPos" - this is where you will store the enemy "origin" point.
2.  In Start(), save your starting position with something like "this.enemyStartPos = this.transform.position;"   Then, whenever you are done chasing, you can move back toward this.enemyStartPos just as you were moving toward player while chasing.  
Hope that helps!

Comment: Oh, also.. on the NavMesh question - I haven't actually used NavMesh but from what I understand of it I would say it is most likely better in the long-run (for things like avoiding obstacles, etc), but for initial basic learning you may find it easier to keep it simple and just do point-to-point like you have in our example above.

Comment: I edited the script, but skeleton stops after I leave the area in which he can see me, he doesnt come back to origins point. Any idea what i have to change ? Gizmos is only to see enemy range and it works.